# facet_wrap() is not plotting by crashing with geom_rect()

Tags: facet-wrap, geom

I am trying to plot the growth of my plants. But I want to highlight the different stages with a geom_rect() of different colors. My code does it when it is all together, but when dividing them with facet_wrap() I get an aes() error, can somebody have a look at it and suggest something?

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): fill
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9Vew.png) -> [Looking for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Htud.png)

Code:

```
Growth_Phase = data.frame(Begin_x=c(0,5,21),End_x=c(5,21,50), 
                          Begin_y=c(-Inf, -Inf, -Inf), 
                          End_y=c(Inf, Inf, Inf),
                          Period_Label=c("Dark \nGermination","Nursery","Farm"))

Plant_Height = ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~Cultivar, nrow=3) +
  geom_rect(data=Growth_Phase, mapping=aes(xmin=Begin_x, xmax=End_x, ymin=Begin_y, ymax=End_y), 
                 fill=c("gray","light blue","light green"), color="black", alpha=0.3) +
  stat_summary(Plant_Development, mapping=aes(x=Day, y=Height, group=Type),
               fun.data=mean_se, geom = "errorbar", color="black", size=1, width = 1, na.rm = T) +
  stat_summary(Plant_Development, mapping=aes(x=Day, y=Height, colour=Type),
               fun="mean", geom = "line", size=1, na.rm = T) +
  stat_summary(Plant_Development, mapping=aes(x=Day, y=Height, colour=Type),
               fun="mean", geom = "point", size=2, shape=16, na.rm = T) +
  geom_label(data=Growth_Phase, aes(x=Begin_x+(End_x-Begin_x)/2, y=18, label=Period_Label), 
               color="black", size=3, fontface = "bold") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,50,5), limits=c(0,50)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,20,5), limits=c(0,20)) + 
  labs(title = "Average plant height", x="Day",  color = "", y = "Plant Height (cm)", caption = "Cesar Figueroa Lopez") +
  theme(title = element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=18), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=18),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=18), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=18),
        legend.text = element_text(size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(size=18),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        strip.text = element_text(size=20))
Plant_Height
```